# Python Memory Game with Tkinter - Trouble with definitions and buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a memory game and am running into a problem with the buttons.  I create the buttons using a for loop and place them into an array, but I have no idea how to call a definition OnButtonClick for each one of them.  Each button should have a random picture, chosen from eight options, with no more than two duplicates.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import random

root = Tkinter.Tk()

poop=PhotoImage(file="poop.gif")
apple=PhotoImage(file="apple.gif")
earth=PhotoImage(file="earth.gif")
fish=PhotoImage(file="fish.gif")
frowny=PhotoImage(file="frowny.gif")
heart=PhotoImage(file="heart.gif")
smiley=PhotoImage(file="images.gif")
water=PhotoImage(file="water.gif")
back=PhotoImage(file="card back.gif")

images = [poop,apple,earth,fish,frowny,heart,smiley,water]
row = 1
column = 0
buttonList=[]

def OnButtonClick():
    self.Button.config(image=random.choice(images))

for i in range(16):
    buttonList.append(Button(root, image=back,       width=150,height=250,command=OnButtonClick()))
buttonList[i].grid(row = row,column = column)


column += 1
if column == 4:
    column = 0
    row += 1





root.mainloop()
```

How would I go about changing the picture when the buttons are pressed?

Comment: The same way you generated them, you'll need to go through an access each (the specific element) element in the array to change the image(s).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check if your code is working properly but if it works than you have to do something like this:

```
def OnButtonClick(number):
    buttonList[number].config(image=random.choice(images))

for i in range(16):
    buttonList.append(Button(root, image=back,width=150,height=250,command=lambda e=i: OnButtonClick(e)))
    buttonList[i].grid(row=row, column=column)
```